# BASH: If condition uses result from find command to determine which file will be written

Tags: bash, if-statement, find, filenames, spaces

I want to list all files in a nested directory, but in that directory has some files which having space in their name. So I wanna write down the paths of which files don't have space in their name and which have in 2 different files.

So far, I just know how to find those having space in their name by this command:

```
find /<my directory> -type f -name * *
```

I want something like:

```
find /<my directory> -type f
   if [ name has space]
   then > a.txt
   else > b.txt
   fi
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check if this works `find /<my directory> -type f -name * * > a.txt; find /<my directory> -type f -name * > b.txt`

Comment: @LohitGupta That will include the files whose name *does* contain a space in `b.txt`. Also, you have some quoting errors (though copied from the question).

Comment: You need quotes around the parameter to the `-name` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a condition in a brief `-exec`.  This is somewhat more complex than you would hope because `-exec` cannot directly contain shell builtins.

```
find "$path" -type f -exec sh -c 'for f; do
    case $f in *\ *) dest=a;; *) dest=b;; esac;
    echo "$f" >>$dest.txt
  done' _ {} +
```

In other words, pass the found files to the following `sh -c ...` script. (The underscore is to populate `$0` with something inside the subshell.)

If the directory tree isn't too deep, perhaps it would be a lot easier to just run `find` twice.

```
find "$path" -type f -name '* *' >a.txt
find "$path" -type f \! -name '* *' >b.txt
```

Comment: I tried and get missing reply: find: missing argument to `-exec' . And my directory quite big so I need to combine find and if in order to save time.

Comment: My original answer lacked the `{}` but I edited it when I noticed.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Use two separate commands:

```
find "$path" -type f -name '* *' > a.txt
find "$path" -type f -not -name '* *' > b.txt
```